# R S4 setMethod '[' distinguish missing argument?

Tags: r, oop, r-s4

Apologies for the title, not sure how else to phrase this question.

If I want to create `setMethod` on a class how can I distinguish between the similar cases of `mat[i,]` and `mat[i]`?

I know for the former I can use:

```
setMethod("[",
    signature(x = "foo", j = "missing", drop = "missing"),
    function(x,i,j,drop) return(myFunc(x,i))
)
```

How can I set a method to distinguish the latter where I wouldn't want to select rows but elements as in the `base` `matrix` class?

Looking at the `?[` documentation I expected something like the following would work:

```
setMethod("[",
    signature(x = "foo", i = "numeric"),
    function(x,i,j,drop) return(myFunc(x,i))
)
```

but it conflicts with any previously defined methods where `j` and `drop` are missing.

The idea being the same as

```
mat <- matrix(seq(9), 3, 3)

mat[c(1,3),]
1 4 7
3 6 9

mat[c(1,3)]
[1] 1 3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will find a lot of examples in the Matrix package. It uses S4 and implements new classes and methods for matrices. As far as I know there is no way to declare what you are looking for in the signature. Instead you have to use the function `nargs` to distinguish between `mat[1]` and `mat[1, ]`. Here is an example how to do that:

```
setClass("foo", slot = c(mat = "matrix"))

setMethod(
  "[",
  signature(x = "foo", i = "missing", j = "missing", drop = "missing"),
  function(x, i, j, drop = FALSE) {
    x
  }
)

setMethod(
  "[",
  signature(x = "foo", i = "numeric", j = "missing", drop = "missing"),
  function(x, i, j, ..., drop) {
    if (nargs() == 3) x@mat[i, ]
    else x@mat[i]
  }
)

setMethod(
  "[",
  signature(x = "foo", i = "numeric", j = "numeric", drop = "missing"),
  function(x, i, j, ..., drop) {
    x@mat[i, j]
  }
)

mat <- new("foo", mat = matrix(seq(9), 3, 3))

mat[]
mat[2:5]
mat[1:2, ]
mat[1:2, 2]
```

However, it would be easier if you directly extend the base class 'matrix' (or 'Matrix' from the Matrix package) and do something like

```
setClass("Matrix", contains = "matrix")
```

since you get these methods for free. Note for example, that in the implementation above, you still have to take care of the argument `drop`. And basically you have to reimplement what is already there.